# Calling SP 2016 on-prem REST API using VUE js

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to call the SP 2016 on-prem REST API on 3rd party VUE.js application(cross domain), and struggling on the authentication issue.

1. To avoid the cross domain issue, I try to call REST API via SP.RequestExecutor.js. But in Network tab, I see "401 Unauthorized" on the request of AppWebProxy.aspx when the following code runs.

   ```
   var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
   executor.executeAsync(
   {
       url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
       method: "GET",
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
       success: successHandler,
       error: errorHandler
   });
   ```

1.2. When I try to test the REST API `http://www.example.com/_api/Web/Lists('{guid}')/items`, it shows below error -

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
>           "message": {
>               "lang": "en-US",
>               "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
>           }
>       } }

My question is that how to pass the authentication when I call the REST API in js code?